# Is it possible to filter columns by the sum of their values in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm loading a sparse table using PySpark where I want to remove all columns where the sum of all values in the column is above a threshold.

For example, the sum of column values of the following table:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|  f|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  0|  1|  1|  0|  0|
|  1|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|  1|  0|  0|  1|  1|  1|
|  1|  0|  0|  1|  1|  1|
|  1|  1|  0|  0|  1|  0|
|  0|  0|  1|  0|  1|  0|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Is 5, 2, 2, 3, 4 and 2. Filtering for all columns with sum >= 3 should output this table:

```
+---+---+---+
|  a|  d|  e|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|  0|
|  1|  0|  0|
|  1|  1|  1|
|  1|  1|  1|
|  1|  0|  1|
|  0|  0|  1|
+---+---+---+
```

I tried many different solutions without success. `df.groupBy().sum()` is giving me the sum of column values, so I'm searching how I can then filter those with threshold and get only the remaining columns from the original dataframe.

As there are not only 6 but a couple of thousand columns, I'm searching for a scalable solution, where I don't have to type in every column name. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `collect` (or a `first`) step.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

sum_result = df.groupBy().agg(*(F.sum(col).alias(col) for col in df.columns)).first()

filtered_df = df.select(
    *(col for col, value in sum_result.asDict().items() if value >= 3)
)

filtered_df.show()
+---+---+---+
|  a|  d|  e|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|  0|
|  1|  0|  0|
|  1|  1|  1|
|  1|  1|  1|
|  1|  0|  1|
|  0|  0|  1|
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Very useful, it really saved my day! Also I put an extra `F.when(col(c).isNotNull(),1))` in the `F.sum` as there are values > 1 and I only want to count occurrences of != 0. Seems like an elegant solution overall.

Comment: @ArnoXf I'm not sure to understand the need ot the `when` part. In the end, you just want to keep columns with at least one not null value, don't you ?

Comment: Not exactly. The real data set sometimes includes 2s or 3s and not only 0s (`null` in real data set) and 1s. I want to count occurences of `one or more`, that's why I'm telling the sum to treat everything as 1 when its not null.